# обработка динамического количества форм

Tags: javascript, html

есть html страница на которую по событию добавляются поля ввода с отправкой post запроса по нажатию кнопки. как написать скрипт обработки кнопок submit при их динамическом количестве?
код формы

```html
<form action="/" method="post" id="{{ message["uuid"] }}" name="send_post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ message["user"] }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="uuid" value="{{ message["uuid"] }}">
    <input name="comment" type="text" placeholder="{{ _('type comment here')}}">
    <button type="submit">отправить</button>
</form>
```

код для одной кнопки

```js
window.onload = function(){
     var socket = new SocketHandler();
     var form = document.getElementById('messageform');
     form.onsubmit = function(e){
        socket.send_message(form);
        return false;
     };
};
```

при его сериализации comment отправляется только при нажатии кнопки самой нижней формы, в остальных случаях это поле отправляется пустым

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByName('send_post');
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var form = elems[i];
    form.onsubmit = function(e){
        socket.send_message(form);
        return false;
    };
};
```

что нужно изменить/добавить чтобы отправка работала со всех кнопок форм при их неизвестном заранее количестве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('send_post');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].onsubmit = function(e){
        socket.send_message(this); // !!! form -> this
        return false;
    };
};
```

Comment: спасибо! так заработало.

Comment: @ДмитрийМакаров Пожалуйста. Легко отвечать на хорошо заданный вопрос. Успехов!